# Uncaught ReferenceError: BlueprintJsCore is not defined Botpress

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blueprint, botpress

I have applied this ([Issue](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/pull/3175/)) fix to my exiting **Botpress** of `12.7.2`, now when I click on any bot from the admin screen I get the following image error in the console saying

[image]

> Uncaught ReferenceError: BlueprintJsCore is not defined at
> Object…/ui-shared/dist/index.js (index.js:1) at r (index.js:1) at
> Module…/ui-shared/dist/index.js (index.js:20) at r (index.js:1) at
> Object. (index.js:20) at r (index.js:1) at index.js:1 at
> Object…/ui-shared/dist/index.js (index.js:1) at webpack_require
> (bootstrap:78) at
> Object…/src/web/components/Content/CreateOrEditModal.tsx
> (CreateOrEditModal.tsx:19) at webpack_require (bootstrap:78) at
> Object…/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js!./src/web/components/Content/Select/Widget.tsx
> (Widget.tsx:81) at webpack_require (bootstrap:78) at Object.
> (Widget.tsx-exposed:1) at
> Object…/node_modules/expose-loader/index.js?BotpressContentPicker!./src/web/components/Content/Select/Widget.tsx-exposed
> (web.1aee3449296a502015eb.js?bace44a3ccc1637faed8:140013) at
> webpack_require (bootstrap:78)

and in the terminal, I get the following error when loads

> Could not finish training NLU model { generatedMessage: false, name:
> ‘AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]’, code: ‘ERR_ASSERTION’, actual:
> false, expected: true, operator: ‘==’ }

and after few seconds it shows below error message;

> 04/16/2021 17:25:36.018 Launcher Unhandled Rejection [Error, No
> provider could successfully fullfil request “/vectorize” for lang
> “en”] STACK TRACE Error: No provider could successfully fullfil
> request “/vectorize” for lang “en” at
> RemoteLanguageProvider.queryProvider
> (F:\Naveed\tacbot\out\binaries\modules.cache\module__8318a8352dadf4a5611c84f04ea076b260f5e87cbfa58bfed45fc58cdf085ec6\dist\backend\language\language-provider.js:341:11)
> 04/16/2021 17:25:36.194 Launcher Unhandled Rejection [Error, No
> provider could successfully fullfil request “/vectorize” for lang
> “ar”] STACK TRACE Error: No provider could successfully fullfil
> request “/vectorize” for lang “ar” at
> RemoteLanguageProvider.queryProvider
> (F:\Naveed\tacbot\out\binaries\modules.cache\module__8318a8352dadf4a5611c84f04ea076b260f5e87cbfa58bfed45fc58cdf085ec6\dist\backend\language\language-provider.js:341:11)
> 04/16/2021 17:25:37.502 Launcher Unhandled Rejection [Error, No
> provider could successfully fullfil request “/vectorize” for lang
> “en”] STACK TRACE Error: No provider could successfully fullfil
> request “/vectorize” for lang “en” at
> RemoteLanguageProvider.queryProvider
> (F:\Naveed\tacbot\out\binaries\modules.cache\module__8318a8352dadf4a5611c84f04ea076b260f5e87cbfa58bfed45fc58cdf085ec6\dist\backend\language\language-provider.js:341:11)

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. clone `botpress` version 12.7.2
2. go this fix [cannot create content when in a modal #3175](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/pull/3175/)
3. go to the Files changed tab, which shows 13 files
4. manually add/remove changes to your project as per tracks in every file

Comment: When you apply patch, what was the process taken for that?

Comment: I manually changed the files in my local directory

Comment: For folks who can help you to solve this, it's very difficult to guess that procedure and reproduce it. The error messages and method of application is very vague. I request you to improve your question with some steps to reproduce.

Comment: @NagarajTantri I have updated the reproduction way in my question.

Comment: wouldn't this be a question better answered by the project maintainers?

Comment: @Claies I already posted this same question to their official forum, it looks, they reply with some delay.

Answer (score 0):

You do not modify your files this way (manually editing files)

Though not encouraged for public repository - if you are in a hurry, and cannot wait for the fix release, you should probably try cloning the commit instead of modifying files one by one.

In your case, the commit points to this repo and you should clone this repo instead.

https://github.com/botpress/botpress/tree/d0edf13f0b19c66513b39062d2d03f96d6c669b4

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/botpress/botpress/tree/d0edf13f0b19c66513b39062d2d03f96d6c669b4` says repository not found

Comment: you need to follow the cloning instructions here https://coderwall.com/p/xyuoza/git-cloning-specific-commits . You clone the botpress repository then you checkout the specific commit. Alternatively you download the zip from github.